# Power BI: SUMMARIZE table needing Leading Zeros

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way to use SUMMARIZE to create a table and add padding to one of the columns?

I am using

```
SUMMARIZE(products,products[Appl_No])
```

and would like to have the [Appl_No] to be 6 digits at all times.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add DAX measure for displaying results in format you want. And put that measure in your `SUMMARIZE` function.

```
NewMeasure = FORMAT( [WhateverValue] , "000000" )
```

[WhateverValue] can be a column name or a measure.

[FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax) is the function you need.

[Custom numeric formats for the FORMAT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/custom-numeric-formats-for-the-format-function)

```
SUMMARIZE(products, FORMAT(products[Appl_No], "000000"))
```